# What OAuth Flow does Angularfire/Firebase implement?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on, angularfire

I can't figure out what exactly is the flow used by applications that rely on Firebase for single sign-on authentication.

I know most SPA and client applications uses the "implicit flow", basically because everything happen in the browser, and there is no back-channel, so the application retrieves the auth token directly.

But is that the case for Firebase too? 
Let's say we have an Angular2+ web application, that uses Firebase and AngularFire library to implement Single Sign-On authentication with one of the available providers (i.e. Facebook, Google, ...)

Firebase acts as a back-end for the application, so what is exactly the authentication flow being used in that case? 
Is the safer "authorization code" one or the simpler "implicit flow" one?

I read through Firebase documentation but I wasn't able to find any specific info about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the authorization code flow for supported OAuth 2.0 providers (Google, Facebook and GitHub). At the end of the flow, the code is exchanged for access tokens or ID token too (google case) using the secret you configured with your provider in the Firebase Console.

Comment: So is the secure back channel established between Firebase and the providers? If it's like so I guess the client application doesn't get or store any token, but just the final answers (i.e. json objects) if the token is ok for the provider. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah Firebase Auth will exchange the authorization code with the provider directly. No OAuth tokens are stored on the server, nor on the client. But Firebase Auth will return whatever OAuth access tokens or id tokens the providers returns back to the client.